# gcloud command to get list of all load balancers in gcp

Tags: gcloud

I know how to get list of loadbalancers in a specific project. Can someone help me out on how i can get list of all loadbalancers along with all its configurations and details of all GCP projects (i have multiple projects).

i am able to get details for a single project by using the command below
`gcloud compute forwarding-rules list --format=json | jq -r '.[] | [.name, .IPAddress, .region, .protocols] | @csv' > load_balancers.csv`

need a command so i can export it also

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for PROJECT in $(gcloud projects list --format='value(PROJECT_ID)') do
    gcloud compute forwarding-rules list --project $PROJECT --format=json | jq -r '.[] | [.name, .IPAddress, .region, .protocols] | @csv' > load_balancers.csv
done
```

Comment: the `.name` is the name of the forwarding-rule but not load balancer